# How to create a function that triggers whenever a new sheet is created?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a sheet of modification times for each of my other sheets. For example, I have a 'Signing' and 'Profile' sheet, and in my modifications times sheet I have:

| Sheet Name | Modification Time |
| --- | --- |
| Signing | 1639335205000 |
| Profile | 1639335207338 |

I want to create a function that, whenever I create another sheet, automatically adds it to the modifications times sheet as a new row.

I have looked at ScriptApp triggers and events but haven't found anything that is related(onEdit for example might be useful if there was a way to know if the edit was creating a sheet (if it even catches those events) but would also be triggered all the time).

Answer (score 0):

I've actually wondered this myself and I hope someone can post a better answer than my method.

First, I create a named range that's going to store the number of sheets in the workbook (in below code I used `sheetCount`). Make sure this is at the workbook level (which by default google does).

Then leverage onEdit with this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //var range = e.range;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const storedSheetCount = ss.getRange("sheetCount")//<-- need to setup named range
  var sCount = ss.getNumSheets();
  if(storedSheetCount.getValue()!=sCount){
    if(storedSheetCount.getValue()<sCount){
      // more
      Browser.msgBox("You addeded a spreadsheet!")
    }else{
      //for less
      Browser.msgBox("you took one away")
    }
    //both cases update the value
    storedSheetCount.setValue(sCount); //<--- updates stored count
  }
}
```

I am **well** aware that this is not ideal for a variety of reasons including:

**No code is executed until an edit ACTUALLY happens.**

Stated differently, adding a sheet is not an edit event, so a user must then click into a cell or delete a blank one to kickoff the procedure.

**Takes up space on the spreadsheet front end.**

I hate helper columns/cells. `Names` is one area that Excel definitely crushes GoogleShhets as it allows direct references to values. Thus with Excel, I could avoid cluttering a spreadsheet by setting a named rage to the sheetCount (ie. `refersTo:=3`). One alternative to this would be to use the spreadsheet's file description, but this requires granting permissions to Drive Service which opens up all kinds of security risks for such a trivial request.

If anyone can do better, please share.

Comment: You could use metadata : Spreadsheet.addDeveloperMetadata("key", "value").  The manipulation is however cumbersome (getDeveloperMetadata() returns an array, loop and compare key).  Using cells make it easier to control what's happening and are easier to change (formatting, number of columns) if necessary.